# Prepend URL to all clicks with absolute paths executed on a page

Tags: javascript, click, href, event-listener, absolute-path

I have this issue with advertising agencies delivering ads with no parameters for click tracking URLs.

In my example, the click URL will be:
http://landing-page.com

My tracking URL will be:
http://tracker.com?url=

The desired effect is, that when a user clicks on any link on the creative, he will be sent to:

http://tracker.com?url=http://landing-page.com

The catch is, that the links are defined by using `<a>` tags or a `click` `eventListener`s. Either with `onclick` or `addEventListener('click', func)`)

I can iterate through all `a[href^=http]`s.

How do I catch/prepend my URL to the event listeners?

Many thanks in advance

EDIT:

So for the `href`s I am doing something like this:

```html
<script>
  var links = adContainer.querySelectorAll('a[href^=http]');
  window.adclick = 'http://tracker.com?url='
  for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    (function(i) {
      links[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        window.open(window.adclick + links[i].href, '_blank');
        e.preventDefault();
      });
    })(i);
  }
</script>
```

The issue I have, is that I cannot work out, or find out online how to do something similar with an event listener.

Comment: Some of your code snippet could help, try to add something more.

Comment: Cheers lamp76 - I have updated my initial post.

Comment: Following my solution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After some more trying, I have found a dead easy solution.

I should still check if the URL starts with `http` - but you get the gist:

```js
window._open = window.open;

window.open = function(url, target) {
  window._open('http://tracker.com?url=' + url, target);
}
```

Comment: This will change the window.open for all the links of the page, not only for the request links.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Sorry, I failed to mention that the ads are all delivered within their own frames.\

Answer (score 1):

Simply try  to change:

```
    window.open(window.adclick + links[i].href, '_blank');
```

in

```
    window.open(window.adclick + this.href, '_blank');
```

so try this:

```
<script>
  var links = adContainer.querySelectorAll('a[href^=http]');
  window.adclick = 'http://tracker.com?url='
  for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
      links[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        window.open(window.adclick + this.href, '_blank');
        e.preventDefault();
      });
  }
</script>
```

Comment: That part was working fine, although you have simplified it for me a lot now. Thank you for that.

The initial problem, I have solved above :)